# Can't really understand constructor and prototype relationship in Javascript

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

I'm a beginner in Javascript, and having hard times trying to understand the relationship between constructor and prototype properties.

I know that Prototype object has a `constructor` property that points to constructor function. And the constructor function has a `prototype` property that points back to the prototype object.

Here's a code i'm trying to understand with (my questions are commented in the code) :

```
function Car(){};
var myCar = new Car();
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(myCar)); //why this prints "Car" Object ? isn't it the constructor not the prototype object ? why the prototype object is not printed ?


var Vehicle = {
    getName : function(){
        return "hello";
    }
};
Car.prototype = Vehicle ; //I'm trying to change the prototype property in the constructor to "Vehicle" Object is that done right ?
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(myCar).getName()); //Why am i getting getName() function does not exist ?
```

Comment: The `constructor` property is pretty much useless. It has no practical purpose and can be overwritten by script so is unreliable.

Comment: You may want to look at this: http://pivotallabs.com/users/pjaros/blog/articles/1368-javascript-constructors-prototypes-and-the-new-keyword

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> why this prints "Car" Object ? isn't it the constructor not the prototype object ? why the prototype object is not printed ?

That's just how Chrome (or the browser you use) names the object. If you have a close look at the properties, it really is `Car.prototype`:

[image]

> I'm trying to change the prototype property in the constructor to "Vehicle" Object is that done right ?

You cannot change the prototype of an existing object, you can only extend it. Setting `Car.prototype = Vehicle;` will only change the prototype for **future** instances of `Car`, the existing ones will still refer to the original prototype object, which doesn't have a `getName` property:

```
// create a new instance after setting the new prototype
var myCar2 = new Car();
// yields false
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(myCar) === Object.getPrototypeOf(myCar2));
```

---

This really does not have anything to do with prototypes, but just how assignment and references work in JavaScript. Imagine I have the following object:

```
var foo = {
    bar: {
        answer: 42
    }
};
```

and assume I assign `foo.bar` to a property of an other object:

```
var baz = {};
baz.xyz = foo.bar;
```

Setting `foo.bar` to some other value now, like `foo.bar = {}`, won't change the value of `baz.xyz`, it will still refer to the previous object.

Only **extending** the original object (extending the prototype), or changing its properties will have an effect, since both, `foo.bar` and `baz.xyz` refer to the same object:

```
foo.bar.answer = 21;
console.log(baz.xyz.answer); // shows 21
// console.log(foo.bar === baz.xyz); // yields true
```